# Facebook share dialog is dismissed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've got this issue in my application:

- I've implemented a fully functional Facebook Share Dialog - works great on my testing device (I've added the dev key hash to FB platform)
- I've generated a signed apk for release (I've added the release key hash to FB platform, too).
- I test the release signed apk on my device (Nexus5) - works great
- I test the release signed apk on other devices - it is dismissed a second after I show it.

Has anyone got any idea what's up with this behaviour? I cannot find a reasonable why it would do this.

Also, later, I've clear the data from the FB app on that device and it worked well. I can't tell if it will or won't work on the user's devices, and I cannot assume that the users will clear their FB app data just to make my app work, so I'm not sure exactly what should I do.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. The app was still on Development mode in Facebook Dashboard. I switched to Public and it worked

Comment: That was what messed me up in the first place. I guess Facebook kept de device ID and knew that it is used for development and testing purposes and it allowed it to access Facebook API calls

Comment: For face book session token not using device id,its using email id admin authoriser or tester.You can get the same result even login with same credential with another device.

Comment: That's entirely possible. Anyway, it just seemed weird to me. It is true that on other device I was logged in with another account, so you may be right. Anyway, glad I fixed the problem. Hope it helps anyone who is having the same issue

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I did the same setting from facebook. I changed development mode to public. But still the same. How did you clear the facebook authorization cash?

Answer (score 0):

there are two keyhashes to be added on the facebook dev account

1. the debug keyhash which is generated when you run the application from eclipse
2. the keyhash generated after apk is made.

Comment: Have you actually read my question? I said there that I've added BOTH my dev and my release key hashes on the fb dev console.

Comment: I don't believe that posting my code would give you any information regarding my issue. As I said, the Dialog works well on dev apk